# UIActivityType – Property cannot be an @objc override because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, xcode8-beta6

While updating to Xcode 8 Beta 6, from what I saw a new type got introduced: `UIActivityType`

So I tried to do somewhere like this in my `UIActivity` custom class:

```
class FooActivity: UIActivity {
    func retrieveActivityType() -> String {
        return "someStringDescribingActivityType"
    }

    override open var activityType: UIActivityType? {
        @objc(retrieveActivityType)
        get {
            return UIActivityType(rawValue: "someStringDescribingActivityType")
        }
    }
}
```

where `retrieveActivityType()` is the Objective-C equivalent since `UIActivityType` is only defined in Swift. But no luck so far, still having two errors:

1. `Property cannot be an @objc override because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`
2. `'@objc' getter for non-'@objc' property`

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: If the type only exists in Swift, defining a different name for the getter doesn't help.

Comment: Aside: if `UIActivityType` is not a `UIKit` type, I recommend renaming it.  It's confusing.

Comment: This is an issue if you are simply extending the class `UIActivityItemProvider` and overriding any of the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol methods (specifically the one that provides the subject for the activity type).

The error is:

"Method cannot be an @objc override because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C"

Answer (score 1):

Found a quick fix by just making the return type as **non-optional**.
I guess there is no real workaround until beta 7 gets released.

```
class FooActivity: UIActivity {
    override open var activityType: UIActivityType {
    get {
        return UIActivityType(rawValue: "someStringDescribingActivityType")
    }
}
```

Sources:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2344

https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/4360